# How can we factorise a general second degree expression?

Tags: conic-sections

The expression:

$$13x^2 - 18xy +37y^2 + 2x +14y -2 = 0$$

What I tried was making factors like $(x-a)(y-b)+ $ other terms.

$$\left(x-\dfrac{7}{9}\right)\left(y-\dfrac{1}{9}\right)+\dfrac{2}{81}-\dfrac{13x^2}{18}-\dfrac{37y^2}{18}=0$$

Actually, I **do not want** to completely factorise the expression, but only make it into groups of factors so that I can easily **identify the conic** that it represents.

The method that we were taught was by calculating $\Delta$, given by:

$$\Delta = abc +2fgh-af^2-bg^2-ch^2$$

and cases on when it represents which conic. **But** the problem asks for **elements** of conic too, like focus, directrix etc. These can be identified only when we have it in proper factorised form, which I am unable to do.

Please suggest ways of factorisation as a general rule.

Comment: There are several questions like this on MSE, e.g., see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578004/factorization-of-polynomial-fx-y). There are many ideas for factorizing $f(x,y)$, but they have certain restrictions - see for example the article by [M. Zieve](http://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~zieve/papers/kaloyan.pdf).

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections

Comment: this may help. you can get the solution without verbiage or the solution with how it was done. If you click on methods ( on the left ), you get the whole theory.
https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=iGgNBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This book seems to do conic sections](https://books.google.com/books?id=iGgNBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the first twenty pages or so, although the online preview shows only the end of the chapter. It would appear they do not require linear algebra before this material, so that might be an advantage. They do a hyperbola on page E-24, an ellipse pages E-27 to E-29, then exercise E-29 to E-30, just the final answers pages E-30 to E-32. This book is Geometry & Vector Calculus
by A. R. Vasishtha.

Here is the treatment of a different ellipse, pages E-27 to E-29. If not clear, you can go to the web preview and compare.

[image]

[THIS SEEMS TO BE](http://www.laxmipublications.com/servlet/lpgetbiblio?bno=001055) a good book for this, extra practice problems and solutions, to go with an existing textbook in engineering mathematics.  To get anywhere with this problem, basic linear algebra and simple multivariable calculus (partial derivatives) are required, unless you are able to memorize a large number of formulas.
An edition of the main textbook [seems available here](http://www.faadooengineers.com/threads/45276-Engineering-Mathematics-by-NP-Bali-pdf-free-Download). Maybe safe to use, maybe not. I cannot seem to find conic sections in this book, though. They jump to three dimensional stuff.

Te center of the ellipse is at $(1/4, 1/4).$   If we take translated coordinates $(p,q)$ with
$$  p = x + \frac{1}{4}, \; \; q = y + \frac{1}{4},   $$ or
$$  x = p - \frac{1}{4}, \; \; y = q - \frac{1}{4},   $$
we get
$$ 13 p^2 - 18 pq + 37 q^2 = 4. $$

For the next part, a rotation, you need to deal with eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Not bad, they deliberately made the eigenvalues integers. However, square roots do appear.

Let
$$  u = \frac{3}{\sqrt {10}} p + \frac{1}{\sqrt {10}} q, $$
$$  v = - \frac{1}{\sqrt {10}} p + \frac{3}{\sqrt {10}} q, $$ or
$$  p = \frac{3}{\sqrt {10}} u - \frac{1}{\sqrt {10}} v, $$
$$  q = \frac{1}{\sqrt {10}} u + \frac{3}{\sqrt {10}} v. $$

Then 
$$ 10 u^2 + 40 v^2 = 4. $$

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have the conic as $$Q(x,y) = 13x^2-18xy+37y^2+2x+14y-2=0$$ Comparing with the standard form $$Q(x,y) = Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$ we get, $A=13, B=-18, C=37, D=2, E=14, F=-2$. To determine the type of conic, we create a matrix 
$$ A_Q =\begin{bmatrix}
A & B/2 & D/2\\
B/2 & C & E/2\\
D/2 & E/2 & F
\end{bmatrix}$$
and then classify the conic as follows:

$(1)$ If $\det A_Q = 0$, the conic is degenerate.
$(2)$ If $\det A_Q \neq 0$, then we can see what type of conic section it is by computing the minor, $\det A_{{33}}$:
$(a)$ $Q$ is a hyperbola if $\det A_{33} <0$.
$(b)$ $Q$ is a parabola if $\det A_{33}=0$, and
$(c)$ $Q$ is an ellipse if $\det A_{33}>0$.

---

For our conic, we have $$\det A_{33} = \begin{vmatrix} 13 & -9\\ -9 & 37\end{vmatrix} = (13)(37)-(-9)(-9) = 400>0$$ So, it is an ellipse. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you sir, but that is same as finding $\Delta$! Suppose we have that it is an ellipse, then how will we find the focus and directrix? We will need to operate on the expression and mould it in a certain way to find them!